# Finite group of units

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I want to show that the group of units of a number field $K$ is finite $\iff K= \mathbb{Q}$ or $K$ is an imaginary quadratic field.

I know that the units of a number field are precisely the integral elements with norm $\pm1$. Thus they are $\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ and form a finitely generated abelian group of rank $r_1+r_2-1$ where $(r_1,r_2)$ is the signature of $K$.

This means if $K$ is an imaginary quadratic field, then $\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ is a finite cyclic group since it has $r_1=0$ and $r_2=1$ so $r_1+r_2-1=0$, which means it has rank $0$. Thus $K$ imaginary quadratic field $\implies$ group of units of $K$ is finite.

I also know that if $K$ is a real quadratic field, then $\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ is an infinite cyclic group generated by the fundamental element, but I am not sure this is relevant unless used in a contrapositive or contradiction. But I wonder if this is not broad enough.

However, I was under the impression that if $K=\mathbb{Q}$ then $K^\times=K^*=\mathbb{Q}\backslash\{0\}$, which is clearly not finite.

I also have no idea how to tackle the converse direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group of units of a number field is the group of units of the underlying ring of integers of a number field. It sort of is bad terminology but like you mentioned, the units of a field are all the non-zero elements, by definition. So for $\mathbb{Q}$, we are looking at $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}=\{1,-1\}$ since $\mathbb{Z}$ is the ring of integral elements of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now since you already know that the rank is $r_1+r_2-1$, then you note that the unit group is finite if and only if the rank is $0$. So either $r_1=1$ and $r_2=0$ (dimension $1$) or $r_1=0$ and $r_2=1$ (dimension $2$, imaginary). These are exactly the rationals and imaginary quadratic fields.